# Convert Sql Server (MSSQL) datetime column to Unix time in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

Querying SQL Server (MSSQL) columns in PHP (Ubuntu / PHP 5.2.4), my date columns are coming out looking like this:

May 16 2013 12:00:00:000AM

strtotime won't parse them.

Tried this:

```
preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):[0-9]{3}([apmAPM]{2})$/",$time_string,$regs);
$month = $regs[1];
$day = $regs[2];
$year = $regs[3];
$hour = $regs[4];
$minute = $regs[5];
$second = $regs[6];
$ampm = $regs[7];
$converted_time_string = $month." ".$day." ".$year." ".$hour.":".$minute.":".$second.$ampm;

$actual_time = strtotime($converted_time_string);

return $actual_time;
```

But it's having trouble with some dates, for example:

Aug  1 2013 12:00:00:000AM

Any more reliable suggestions on how to do this?  Upgrading PHP not an option at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use `SELECT ... CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), dateColumn, 120) ...` to select the date in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (24h) format - this assures loss-free conversion with `strtotime()`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `date_parse_from_format` could parse it to a associated array. With this array you can create the new timestring.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php